# Understand the current memory utilization for my pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics-server

I want to understand what is the current memory usage for my pod running on EKS Cluster.
I have Metrics server and prometheus installed.

When I run a "kubectl top pods", I get a memory usage of 2.5 GB

```
sh-4.2$ kubectl top pods liink-goquorum-node-learner-quorum-0 -n my-namespace
NAME                                   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
liink-goquorum-node-learner-quorum-0   128m         2577Mi
```

The metrics server [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/tree/master) advises against using this as an accurate source of metrics.

When I go inside the pod and execute the command, my memory usage is vastly different.

```
root@container[liink-goquorum-node-learner-quorum-0]:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
8921739264
```

When I checked in Prometheus (as advised in metrics server github page), my memory utilization is closer to the one that I am getting in the system.

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{cluster="liink-uat",namespace="<my-namespace>",container="",pod="liink-goquorum-node-learner-quorum-0"} => 8923037696
```

However, when I run the below query, the value is closer to metrics server.

```
container_memory_working_set_bytes{cluster="liink-uat",namespace="<my-namespace>",container="",pod="liink-goquorum-node-learner-quorum-0"}  => 2704633856
```

So which one is the best source to get the current memory usage for the pod?
Also if metrics server can't be trusted for accurate usage, then are the auto scaling decisions based on this wrong? What am I missing here?

Below are the explanation of these metrics from the [cadvisor documentation](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md) and it is not very clear to me from this.

> `container_memory_usage_bytes`: Current memory usage, including all memory regardless of when it was accessed
>
> `container_memory_working_set_bytes`: Current working set

Also pasting the cgroups explanation for the memory usage.
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt
which lets me believe that the current container utilization is closer to what I am getting by running the cat command.

Can someone help me understand what is the correct way to get the current memory utilization and if i am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are correct, they just provide information about different utilization categories.

My understanding:

- `container_memory_working_set_bytes` includes memory allocated to your application. This is critical for application functioning, and thus this metric is monitored most of the time and has the most interest. OOM and autoscaling are based on its value.
- `container_memory_usage_bytes` in addition to memory allocated to your application also includes all kinds of memory used by pod: filesystem caching, shared memory, that kind of stuff. Theoretically this memory is not critical and can be freed if needed.

I believe `container_memory_usage_bytes` is closer to "current memory usage for the pod". But you should remember that it is simply not the same as memory usage of application in pod.

Comment: This would make sense but can we control this allotment. Going by your explanation, my application only has 2.5GB memory available and the pod has 8 GB. Can we increase the container_memory_working_set_bytes somehow perhaps by some configuration? How can I make the application consume the entire available memory?

Answer (score 1):

The `container_memory_working_set_bytes` shows the amounts of memory the container recently accessed. If the `container_memory_working_set_bytes` reaches the configured memory limit, then the container is killed with [OOM killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory), since it cannot continue working efficiently without additional memory.

As I understand, the `container_memory_usage_bytes` shows the total memory the container ever allocated or requested. This memory can never be touched (for example, if the container pre-allocates memory and never uses it), or it could be accessed only once (for example, if there is a memory leak). So the `container_memory_usage_bytes` may significantly exceed the `container_memory_working_set_bytes`.

If the `container_memory_usage_bytes` grows over time at a constant rate, and its value exceeds the `container_memory_working_set_bytes`, then there are high chances that the application has a memory leak. If the `container_memory_usage_bytes` remains constant over time, then everything is OK, even if its' value exceeds the `container_memory_working_set_bytes`.

Comment: IIUTC, container_memory_working_set_bytes is equal to the "limits" that one specify in the k8s manifest resources section. Isn't that the highest possible memory allocatable to the container?  Can you expand on what you mean by total memory ever allocated? Can containers be allocated more memory than the limit?